# add entry to list pref android

Tags: android, preferences

I have added a listPref like this in my settings.xml:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Presets" >
    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="1"
        android:entries="@array/pre_entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/pre_values"
        android:key="pre_type"
        android:summary="Choose between various presets"
        android:title="Presets" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Is there any way I can update or add to the entries and entryValues array?
I mean  I know I can create a custom pref and then add the values but is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You can get the entries and their values using `listPreference.getEntries()` and `getEntryValues()`.  Then add the new value to that array (it may be easiest to create a new array and copy them over if you want to insert into the middle).  Then call `setEntries` and `setEntryValues` on the new arrays to set the new list.